# Security Considerations for AG vs Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability, log-shipping

we are considering removing our log shipping server and adding another node to our Availability Groups. While I understand that this should be better cause it's a/synchronous and will move the data to the node faster and can also be used for reporting, I don't know from a security point of view what might be the implications and concerns for the organisation.

Example: in case the primary node becomes infected from some malicious software and effects the logs, what will be the implications on all the other passive nodes.

We still plan to continue taking backups from the primary node frequently, but maybe someone has some experience on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know from a security point of view what might be the implications and concerns for the organisation. [sic]

Nothing changes. It's still a separate OSE (operating system environment), still only has the logins you give it, etc., the only difference is now it's using a continuous log stream and will be coupled with the cluster (so availability may be impacted, but not the system, as compared to log shipping).

> Example: in case the primary node becomes infected from some malicious software and effects the logs, what will be the implications on all the other passive nodes.

None. We send logical changes, if those changes are corrupt or otherwise incorrect it'll be thrown out and you'll receive errors that the log stream is bad.